# onclick not working on button laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am working on Larvel framework. I am using login blade file of auth component. There is one button of register. whren i apply onclick on button to register page it is not redirect to register page.

```
<button class="btn btn-info sign-bttn" onclick="{{ url('/register') }}">Register Your Business</button>
```

Where i am doing wrong anyone help me

Comment: can you display your route or controller logic

Comment: r u using ajax?

Comment: no there is no route of that because i am using auth component of laravel

Comment: on click should have javascript function.

Comment: not the direct url that you have done in the following code.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna redirect, should use `a` element of `HTML`

```
<a class="btn btn-info sign-bttn" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register Your Business</a>
```

Btw, inside `onclick` you need to pass a `javascript` not a string (`{{ url('/register') }}` just pass a string)

Redriect in `javascript` use `window.location.href`

```
<button class="btn btn-info sign-bttn" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url('/register') }}';">Register Your Business</button>
```

Comment: Still not redirect to register page . when i click on register button.It shows up current page